# How to give higher priority for a user thread than kernel thread(work_queues)

Tags: multithreading, linux-kernel, kernel, thread-priority

I am running an application,where certain user threads must not be preempted by kernel .I will explain my setup:
OS:
Linux 2.6.32 kernel

Kernel level:
1.There are many modules which are insmoded into kernel.
2.Work_queues are also initialized in some modules(I guess separate threads are created for work_queues)
3.If I am getting any hardware interrupt,  I would queue this work in any of these initialized work_queue during my isr.

Application level:
there are multiple threads running in parallel,some of which are of higher priority than any other thread in process.(Even kernel)

Objective:
1.If I get any hardware interrupt,isr will be automatically called in which work will be queued for any work_queue.But,I do not want scheduling of these work_queues if higher priority user level threads are running during that time.ie,certain User level threads should not be preempted by any work_queue handling in kernel.Now, i have observed that kernel gets priority than any other user thread.
2.I have multiple work_queues in kernel.How can i give different priority for different work queues.I havent seen any api to set priority for work_queues in kernel.

Comment: I am using Linux 2.6.32 kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User threads must always be pre-emptible by kernel-mode threads because kernel-mode threads need to respond to hardware-events. This is by design.

If your user-mode threads need to interact with the hardware or are real-time and hence must not be pre-empted, consider making them kernel-mode threads.

If you are merely encountering errors caused by your thread being descheduled during a critical operation and ending up with another thread trampling over your operation, then you should implement locking.

If you have a custom need for breaking this fundamental design of the linux-kernel, you will need to change the behaviour of the kernel-mode scheduler.

Comment: As you told,How can I implement locking between kernel and user mode threads?

Comment: How you implement the locking depends on what you are trying to do. For example, if your user mode thread is accessing the filesystem, consider using filesystem-transactions. If your own threads are falling over each other, consider using a critical section (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_section). Ideally all of the critical activity should be performed by your kernel-mode threads. Delegating critical or kernel tasks to user-mode threads can have serious security implications by undermining linux' security model.